# Chaos Mesh on AKS

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, chaos

Can chaos mesh (https://chaos-mesh.org/docs/) run on AKS for Windows Image?
Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, No.

The most of features in Chaos Mesh are depend on Linux namespace and cgruops. So Chaos Mesh could not play well with Windows Container and other VM-based container-runtime.

If you have any ideas, welcome to make an issue on github!